# How to do a Login woth a google account in JMeter

Tags: authentication, jmeter, google-authentication

I try to login into an application that uses a login with Google Accounts. I try with the script recorder but it doesn't work.

Comment: Tell us about the login process. What kind of script? Does it open in html? is it sent over http? Which API you're using? What errors do you encounter.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably login via Google Account is implemented using [OAuth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) protocol and this is not something you can record and replay. Actually you don't need to load test the logging in process itself as it mostly being performed on Google side.

In order to be authenticated you need to supply correct [Authorization Bearer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) token via JMeter's [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager). The token can be obtained using one of the following ways:

- By recording (look for `Authentication: Bearer` token in the HTTP Header Manager
- Using real browser from the [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) and once you're logged in - copy session information from browser into JMeter
- From the [Google Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) if you have permissions
- By performing full authentication process using i.e. [OAuth Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/) from J[SR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

See [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) article for more detailed explanation on each of the approaches.