# I would like to use Jmeter for UI performance testing. How to use Jmeter for UI performance testing?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I would like to use Jmeter for UI performance testing. How to use Jmeter for UI performance testing? Lets say for example if i want to do for gmail or facebook. How do i enter the username/Userid and Password for it? I know that we need to pass parameters for that. But how do I do that? Can anyone please help me out with this. As, I've been stuck at it for a while now.

Comment: Please check

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49854528/6819193

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different types of testing:

1. UI Testing happens on **client** side to wit in your **browser**. So if you need to check i.e. rendering speed or profile JavaScript code execution it would be sufficient to use [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools). If you want to automate this check - take a look at [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) browser automation framework and [Window.performance object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/performance). JMeter will not help you with this as according to [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

   > JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, **JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does** (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).
2. If you need to test the **backend**, for example simulate hundreds/thousands of users concurrently using the application under test you need to simulate browser's network activity. Browsers don't do any magic, they just send [HTTP Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods), receive responses and show them. JMeter can send the requests and receive responses so you just need to figure out what requests are going back and forth. One of the options is using the aforementioned browser developer tools, the requests payload will be visible at "Network" tab. An easier option would be recording your test scenario using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/), this way you will get the test "skeleton" and after some [correlation/parameterization](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) you will be able to replay the recorded test with [increased number of virtual users](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#adding_users).

Answer (score 0):

For UI performance testing you can try following options:

1. Go to google Developer tools >> Lighthouse >> Generate report for categories say performance & best practices
   From Performance audit ,you can get KPIs like Time to interact etc.
   You don't need to create any script for doing this.
2. You can use open source frameworks like sitespeed.io & build a dockerized env to run UI performance run which is basically running chrome headless fashion & capturing performance KPIs
3. There are many online performance analysis sites which runs some solution or other like #2 mentioned above & share report
   one of them is https://www.webpagetest.org/